# How to fix django model manager to work with serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have used model managers in my app to do the heavy lifting.  Was able to use it well for the web version but having difficulty with the serialization of the Query to move data into a mobile app via an API.

The model manager works fine for the web based interface.  Trying to serialize so data can get into React Native for mobile app.  The override of the queryset seems to be the way to go.

here is the code in the serializer:

```
class UserBeltsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserBelts
        fields = ('__all__')
```

here is the code in .api:

```
    class SingleUserBeltViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
        permission_classes = [
            permissions.IsAuthenticated,
        ]
        serializer_class = UserBeltsSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            beltlist = UserBelts.objects.all_belts(user=self.request.user)
            return beltlist
```

error message is as follows:

```
AttributeError at /api/singleuserbelts
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `UserBeltsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Took better part of several hours until I found an obscure reference to this.  My model manager was not returning a pure QuerySet (it was a QuerySet with some additional info the web version was using).  Once I parsed out the QuerySet from the object it normally returned, the error was gone.